# How to access an object's property by name lookup?

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties

I worked a lot in ActionScript and I was pleased to see that it is very similar to C#, but there's one thing that I'm missing, and that is "dynamic referencing".

For example, dynamic referencing can be done using the array operator[]. So for instance you could also access the property `some_thing.something_else` in the following two ways:

```
some_thing["something_else"]
// or

some_thing[some_var] // where some_var is a variable holding a string
// e.g.: some_var = "something_else";
```

In other words, the array syntax is equivalent to specifying the property itself.

The other option to reference an object dynamically is using the eval() global function.

**So, my question: Is it possible to reference properties in C# in a manner similar to ActionScript?**

Comment: ExpandoObjects will work as described by Nathan but I expect your design is probably not informed about the options available in .net -- there are a lot of different types of collections which I expect will be faster and more elegant.   Which to use depends on the problem you are solving -- can you give more detail?

Comment: Hogan, I am trying to access object properties. The method described by Nathan is good for what I need at the moment. Thank you All.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I can see to do this would be using dynamics, and in particular the [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).  With the `ExpandoObject` class you can do things like:

```
dynamic employee;

employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;
```

Despite `employee` not having any of those properties on it, this code will compile and work.  Not only will it work, but dynamic properties are even strongly typed.

Accessing properties by key is also easy.  `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string,object>`, so its as simple as a downcast:

```
var dictEmployee = employee as IDictionary<string,object>;
Debug.WriteLine(dictEmployee["Age"].ToString);
```

This code will result in `33` being printed into the debug output.

I wouldn't suggest using this method pervasively, but it comes in handy on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `eval` in C#.

Regarding first part of your question. While following is perfectly possible in C#

```
var key = "ouch";
Console.WriteLine(something[key]);
```

there're two things worth mentioning.

1. there's nothing dynamic about this code, at least in the C# meaning of dynamic
2. `something` is not an array, but dictionary.

Comment: More info: The member you access if you say e.g. `someThing[someVar]` and `someThing` is not simply an array, is called [an indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C#.